# Copying content of one xml into other using xslt

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I am trying to copy a content from one xml to other xml using Xslt.

I need to copy content of file1

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<products author="Jesper">
  <product>
    <name>Delta</name>
    <price>800</price>
    <stock>
        <price>13a</price>
    </stock>
    <place>Denmark</place>
  </product>
</products>
```

to file 2. File2 has similar tags but order is jumbled,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<products author="Jesper">
  <product>
    <stock>
        <price>13d</price>
    </stock>
    <price>700</price>
    <place>Copenhagen</place>
     <name>Beta</name>
  </product>
</products>
```

**expected output**

```
<products author="Jesper">
  <product>
    <stock>
        <price>13a</price>
    </stock>
    <price>800</price>
    <place>Denmark</place>
     <name>Delta</name>
  </product>
</products>
```

so basically I need to Iterate through  file1 using for-each and then find the matching tag in file2 and copy the tag value. Not sure about an efficient way to do so ... Double iterating is inefficient. Any suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: so you want everything in file2 to be overwritten? or somekind of merge. if the first is the case why to mention file 2 at all. get file 1 and use the xslt to create from scratch

Comment: file2 is having a specified schema which may have few extra tags and may not have all the tags of file 1. I can not change the predefined schema of file 2. So for each tag of file1 I need to perform a look-up  for the tags in file 2 . If found I need to set the value of the tag from file1

Comment: that makes it clear enough! But how you want to do it. just with xslt. i am not sure but i think xslt can not be used to append data to an existing file. In your title you write java and i think it is a java problem not an xslt problem. Perhaps i am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very broad question, but I'll try to give you some pointers that should get you started.  You will probably want to use the `doc()` function to load the files since XSLT only allows you to iterate over a single "main" file.  `doc()` loads a new file into a variable that you can apply templates to and so on.  If you are concerned about the iteration performance, you should learn about `xsl:key` and the `key()` function, which build indexes that will help with that.